# Nodejs load my HTML without the CSS

Tags: html, css, node.js

I did a little program in nodeJS with cloud9 supposed to launch my html. it worked but without the css. I tried many things but i didn't found the solution.

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

fs.readFile('homepage.html', function(err, data) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);

  var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'});
    response.write(data);
    response.end();
  }).listen(8081);
});

console.log("Server running.");
```

my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>My project</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My project</h1>
    <p>coming soon</p>
</body>
```

`

my CSS:

```
h1{
  font-size: 4px;
}
```

i tried by opening only the .html on my browser and my h1 was 4px.

Comment: Can you list the html file

Comment: Is the CSS file accessible over HTTP?

Comment: I edit my post to add HTML.
I don't know Leo, how can i check ?

Comment: @Leo — The source code to the HTTP server is visible. The CSS is definitely not accessible.

Comment: @Quentin Yep, he doesn't even serve the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
> ```

You tell the browser to load `css/style.css`.

The browser asks the server for it.

> ```
> response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
> ```

The server says "Here is some HTML!"

> ```
> response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'});
> ```

Then it says "Here is some CSS!"

Which is very odd. You can send an HTML document **or** a standalone stylesheet. You can't send both at the same time.

> ```
> response.write(data);
> ```

Then the server sends the contents of `homepage.html`

So when the browser asks for the style sheet, it gets another copy of the homepage.

You need to pay attention to [the `request` object](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) which tells you what the browser is asking for. In particular pay attention to the `method` and `url` properties.

You then need to give it the correct response for that particular URL (which should include the *correct* content-type for the file type, and could be a 404 error if it isn't a request for something you were expecting).

At the moment you always send the homepage. If the browser asks for `/`, you send the homepage. If it asks for `/css/style.css`, you send the homepage. If it asks for `/this/does/not/exist`, you send the homepage.

Comment: i'll read and make some research base on your answer to get the solution. 
Thanks for your help i understand a bit mode how browser and server interact